# django: how many queries does this cause?

Tags: python, sql, django, performance

Say I have the following models:

```
class Baz(models.Model):
    winning = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Bar(models.Model):
    baz = models.ForeignKey(Baz)

class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

Now I have an instance of `Foo`, `foo`. How many queries does the following line execute?

```
winning = foo.bar.baz.winning
```

Does it do one for each foreign-key `.`, or is Django smart enough to only do one query here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will require 3 queries.

One to get foo, bar, and baz.

Use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) to get them at once.

```
Foo.objects.get(id=1).select_related('bar__baz__winning')
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a quick way to tell. Install Django Toolbar. Then check out the queries tab. It will give you all sorts of profiling info.

Though I believe +1 query per FK call

Answer (score 1):

Here is the queries for `winning = foo.bar.baz.winning` statement: (I'am not counting Foo.objects.. statemnt)

```
(0.000) SELECT "foo_bar"."id", "foo_bar"."baz_id" FROM "foo_bar" WHERE "foo_bar"."id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
(0.000) SELECT "foo_baz"."id", "foo_baz"."winning" FROM "foo_baz" WHERE "foo_baz"."id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
```

And here is my tip: add logging for django.db.backends in your settings.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django-db-backends

And you will see all your queries in your console. Or install Django debug toolbar as Francis suggesting you.